# Bootstrap Validator for email address

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, validation, jqbootstrapvalidation, bootstrapvalidator

Hi I am using bootstrapValidator. The Email validation count this `emial@email` valid instead of `emial@email.com`.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
   <div class="error-icon">
      <label class="control-label">Email</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="person_email" name="person_email" placeholder="eg: youremail@gmail.com" type="email">
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('#basicBootstrapForm').bootstrapValidator({ 
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        person_email: {
            validators: {
               notEmpty: {
                   message: 'The email address is required'
               },
               person_email: {
                   message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
               }
           }
        },
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `regexp` validator to define expression of email address.

```
regexp: {
  regexp: '^[^@\\s]+@([^@\\s]+\\.)+[^@\\s]+$',
  message: 'The value is not a valid email address'
}
```

Validation script will be

```
$('#basicBootstrapForm').bootstrapValidator({
  feedbackIcons: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  fields: {
    person_email: {
      validators: {
        notEmpty: {
          message: 'The email address is required'
        },
        regexp: {
          regexp: '^[^@\\s]+@([^@\\s]+\\.)+[^@\\s]+$',
          message: 'The value is not a valid email address'
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/436rvcut/)

Comment: Thank you very much I also added \.. after the second last +, so it validated the .com
^[^@\\s]+@([^@\\s]+\\.)+\..[^@\\s]+$

Comment: Thanks for this! I've noticed that capital letters are forbidden by default, is there a way to allow them through regexp?

Comment: `fasi@com.gmail`, `f@gmail.com.123`,`1@gmail.com.1111`, `a_b@b.g` I have checked these and it does accepts them